# Redefining "physics" package vector differential operators

Tags: math-mode, physics

The [`physics` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics?lang=en) defines commands such as `\grad`, `\div` and `\curl` so that any subsequent delimiters are automatically resized (see MWE below). However, they also use a bold nabla. I would like to redefine the commands such that the automatic resizing is preserved but using a regular nabla. Is there any way this is possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\[ \nabla(\frac{a}{b}) \]
\[ \grad(\frac{a}{b}) \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vnabla{}{\nabla}
\begin{document}

\[ \nabla(\frac{a}{b}) \]
\[ \grad(\frac{a}{b}) \]

\end{document}
```

[image]