# Changing every operator in a document

Tags: macros, math-operators

I'm writing notes on vector calculus and have been using the `\curl` and `\div` operators from the `physics` package. Only after a while did I realise that `\curl` uses the bold-face version of `\nabla` rather than just `\nabla`.

Initially, I wanted to make all the bold-face nablas the same as the standard nablas, and managed to do that with this ([from this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384522/redefining-physics-package-vector-differential-operators)):

`\DeclareDocumentCommand\vnabla{}{\nabla}`

However, I think I actually like the bold-face version better and want to change *all the existing* nablas in the document to bold-face, preferably by redefining `\nabla` to produce the bold-face version (rather than manually searching for every single nabla in the document).

How would I do this? Sorry if this question is elementary. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit confusing. Sounds like you had `\nabla`, then changed (some or all?) to `\vnabla`, but now want to change it back?

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea how that command works. All I know is that using that command, all the bold nablas in the `\div` and `\curl` commands turned into the standard `\nabla`. What I want now is for these to turn back (for which I can just get rid of that line in my preamble) and also for all the nablas (i.e., using only the `\nabla` command) in the document to become bold.

Comment: An aside. According to some conventions, bold-face would correspond to a  vector or matrix, whereas regular face to a scalar... So might be necessary to change other symbols for consistency

Comment: @schrödingcöder Del is always a vector operator, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\nabla` command is defined as a character, using `\mathchardef` so to redefine it as a macro you need to create a new version of it that can be made bold in the same way that the `physics` package defines the `\vnabla` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\mathchardef\NABLA"272
\newcommand*{\Nabla}{\boldsymbol\NABLA}
\let\nabla\Nabla
\begin{document}
\[ \nabla(\frac{a}{b}) \]
\[ \grad(\frac{a}{b}) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I tried this and got the "TeX capacity exceeded" error. I was going to say that the problem might be that I used `\grad` as well, but then I noticed you did that too, so I'm not sure what its problem is. I don't think I can provide a MWE, since it seems to be a document-wide issue. For the time-being, I ended up just replacing every `\nabla` in the document with `\grad` using a text editor.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. This is Alan Munn's solution isn't it?

Comment: I tried that, as well as replacing all the `\grad`s with `\nabla`. One of my other packages probably doesn't like the change. Edit: Just saw you changed your comment. By 'that' I meant using `\Nabla` instead of `\grad` or `\nabla`.

Comment: @Trisztan Try to copy-paste only Alan's code in a brand new file.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, it works fine. Like I said, it only has problems in my particular document. Will probably just settle for my `\grad` solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by/how to debug. I've already tried replacing the `\nabla`s.

Comment: You remove half your file from the bottom, just leave `\end{document}`, then you see if it works. If it still doesn't work, then the problem is in the first part. Repeat the operation. Could also be an issue with your preamble.

Comment: Ah ok. I don't think that's necessary, because the 'log window' at the bottom of my editor tells me which line the compiling dies on. It's where the first `\grad` (or `\nabla` or `\Nabla`, if I replace `\grad`) appears in the code, i.e., if the first `\grad` appears later, it dies at a later line. So yeah, it's probably a preamble issue. I think I'll just stick with `\grad` for this document and wrangle with this issue in the next one.

Answer (score 5):

You want to keep the standard `\nabla` somewhere and redefine the command, in order to avoid an infinite loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\nablasymbol}{\nabla}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\nabla}{\bm{\nablasymbol}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\nabla$ (compare with $\nablasymbol$)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you need to know nothing about how `\nabla` is defined to begin with. Also, `\AtBeginDocument` might be necessary if you use one of the math font packages that delay definitions at begin document; it doesn't harm doing it anyway.

If you're using `unicode-math`, the method is similar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\nablasymbol}{\nabla}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\nabla}{\symbf{\nablasymbol}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\nabla$ (compare with $\nablasymbol$)

\end{document}
```

Here `\AtBeginDocument` is certainly needed, because `unicode-math` does much of its job at that moment and we must delay the redefinition after that job.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Unicode math then all variants of nabla are ready in single font. Looking to `unicode-math-table.tex` we get:

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02207}{\nabla          }{\mathalpha}{nabla, del, hamilton operator}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"1D6C1}{\mbfnabla       }{\mathalpha}{mathematical bold nabla}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"1D6FB}{\mitnabla       }{\mathalpha}{mathematical italic nabla}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"1D735}{\mbfitnabla     }{\mathalpha}{mathematical bold italic nabla}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"1D76F}{\mbfsansnabla   }{\mathalpha}{mathematical sans-serif bold nabla}%
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"1D7A9}{\mbfitsansnabla }{\mathalpha}{mathematical sans-serif bold italic nabla}%
```

So, if you want to use bold variant of nabla, you can set

```
\let\nabla=\mbfnabla
```

That is all. More things are simpler with Unicode math.

Comment: Might be a good idea to save the old definition by `\let\oldnabla=\nabla` or something similar so that it can be accessed if needed.

Comment: @Aditya The solution here does not redefine `\nabla` at all. However, should you wish to, that is one thing that’s not simpler in `unicode-math`. The package defers defining most of its symbols until the end of the preamble, so you must wrap the redefinition in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Comment: @Davislor If you don't use LaTeX, then you don't have these problems with Unicode-math.